# Using a c++ shared library in C# in linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to write a wrapper that will have C# code use c++ code to access some software that doesn't accept commands from linux C#.

My C# code (prog.cs in a solution named program):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class prog
{
    [DllImport("libprog.so", EntryPoint = "printMsg")]
    static extern void printMsg(string msg);

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            printMsg("Hello World!");
        }
        catch (EntryPointNotFoundException epnfex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enpfex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this code with C programs and it works, so I'm 99% sure the C# code isn't the problem.

My C++ code (prog2.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printMsg(string msg)
{
    cout << string + 'n';
}
```

linux commands:
    g++ -fpic -c prog2.cpp
    g++ -shared -o libprog.so prog2.o
    ./program.exe

I understand that C++ decorates the functions because they can be overloaded, but none of the methods I've used to get around that have helped.

So far what I have tried to do to fix this before asking:

changing my c++ method to `__dcelspec(dllexport) void printMsg(string msg)`
When I attempt to compile this, I am told g++ `expects a constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token` referring to the `'('` after `__dcelspec`.

I have also tried adding `extern "C"` in before the `__declspec(dllexport)`, using only `extern "C"` instead of `__declspec(dllexport)`, and using `__attribute__((visibilty("default")))` in place of `__declspec(dllexport)`.

I should add that I'm very new to C++, but have been coding in Java and C# for about 3 years.  From what I have read, it seems like I need to do something with a header file (with which I am unfamiliar), a `.DEF` file (with which I have never heard of), or perhaps both.

Comment: header file is irrelevant and .DEF file is windows linker specific.

Comment: Does it compile? If not, can you give us the compiler warnings. If it does compile, can you tell us what happens when you run it?

Comment: It doesn't compile when I use __dcelspec(dllexport) in front of my method.  With the other attempts it compiles and, upon running, throws an EntryPointNotFound Exception which is caught by my C# code.